# fetch the latest file in a folder and upload to s3?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

filename variable is used to get the name of latest file
My aim is to monitor a folder and whenever new file is retrieved, automatically upload it to s3 bucket using boto3.

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
from subprocess 
import call
import os
import boto3
```

session = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id='aws_access_key_id',                               aws_secret_access_key='aws_secret_access_key',
                                region_name='region_name')

s3 = session.client('s3')

```
class Watcher:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dir = os.path.abspath('D:\\project')
        self.observer = Observer()

    def run(self):
        event_handler = Handler()
        self.observer.schedule(event_handler, self.dir, recursive=True)
        self.observer.start()
        try:
            while True:
                time.sleep(5)
        except:
            self.observer.stop()
            print("Error")

        self.observer.join()   

    class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):
        @staticmethod
        def on_any_event(event):
            if event.is_directory:
                return None

        elif event.event_type == 'created':
        print("Received created event - %s." % event.src_path)
        s3.upload_file(Filename=event.src_path, bucket='bucketname, key=test-file-1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    w = Watcher()
    w.run()
```

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: `s3.meta.client.upload_file(Filename, Bucket = 'aaaaa', Key='test-file-1')` on its own should work. Does that line raise some kind of error? The `call([command], shell=True)` doesn't make any sense and should be removed, looks like you've seriously misunderstood something.

Comment: I missed out one line in which I am storing the latest file in a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @alexhall mentioned in the comment, s3.meta.client.upload_file method will upload a file. You can read about boto3 s3 client's upload method documentation here: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file. However, it is a bit silly example they have there, as they are first creating an s3 resource rather than s3 client, and then because s3 resource does not actually have a method to upload file, they revert back to s3 client. You might as well directly create and use s3 client for uploads.

You are also relying on the fact that boto3 uses default session when you create the s3 resource like you did:

boto3.resource('s3')

This would work fine if you are running the code on lambda or if you are in an ec2 instance that has an IAM role configured for it to access s3 but I think you are running this outside AWS, in which case, you can have a boto3.Session() created first using your credentials, and then a client (or resource) can use that session.

```
aws_access_key_id = '<AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID>'
aws_secret_access_key = '<AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY>'
region_name = 'us-east-1'

session = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
                                aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key,
                                region_name=region_name)

s3 = session.client('s3')
```

You can read about Session configuration here: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html

As mentioned above, because you are trying to upload file, and you do not seem to do anything else with it, you may as well directly create an s3 client rather than s3 resource like you did and then get the s3 client using 'meta.client'.

instead of `command = ...` line, you simply use:

```
s3.upload_file(Filename, Bucket = 'aaaaa', Key='test-file-1')
```

You can delete the last line. You would 'call' if you you were running an OS/System command rather than a something within python.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are doing this to learn python (boto3). If so, congrats. 
If not, AWS already provided such [feature](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html). So you keep everything in your code, but shell out to the AWS CLI.